# Regex for first two character of string alphabet and last two should be numeric

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to validate a string like

```
1.AB97CD11
```

Cases

1. Total length of string min=4, max=8
2. First two characters must be alphabetic
3. Last two characters must be numeric.

I tried this Regex, but it does not work for me:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: Yeah seriously.  Show some effort, otherwise no one will answer.  Wait a minute...I already answered.

Comment: regex: '^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}$'
i try this but not working

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4}` as the middle term, to allow for a total of 4-8 characters.  Your current pattern will only allow for 8 characters.

Comment: @Ajithkumar next time you will ask a question, please show your attempts directly in the question

Comment: You are running the regex in PHP or JS? You can do this without regex as well.

Comment: Oh sorry i am new to stack overflow so i dont know

Comment: I am new to programming and as well as web devlopment.. Can any one please tell me how to learn skills to get a job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{0,4}[0-9]{2}$
```

The `{0,4}` width delimiter on the middle characters ensures that the total length must be between 4 and 8 characters.  I am assuming that you only expect uppercase letters.  If the letters could also be lowercase, then use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[a-z]`.

Answer (score -1):

So I guess you want all 3 conditions to be met at the same time.

You want to use quantifiers to specify the number of letters / digits.

`[a-zA-Z]{2}[\w]{0,4}[0-9]{2}`

would do the job.

Explanation taken from https://regex101.com/

```
Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]{2}
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [\w]{0,4}
{0,4} Quantifier — Matches between 0 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{2}
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
```

Comment: `\w` also matches underscore, which the OP did not mention is allowed in the string.

Comment: That's right, but he didn't mention that it's not allowed. Maybe one could use "." as the any character match here as well